# how to return true and false from toggle button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

How to return 1 and 0 value from this button when I click the submit button so that I can save it to Database.

add.blade.php

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-size="large" id="togBtn" name="status" value="1" onclick="getValue()">
```

```
<script>
 function getValue(){
                if (document.getElementById('togBtn').checked) {
                    console.log("Checked");
                    document.getElementById('togBtn').setAttribute("value", "1");

                } else {
                    console.log("Not Checked");
                    document.getElementById('togBtn').setAttribute("value", "0");
                }
                console.log(document.getElementById('togBtn').getAttribute("value"));

            }
</script>
```

My Controller

```
   public function store(CreateRoomTypeRequest $request)
    {

//        dd($request->all());
          $data_room = [
              'room_type'=>$request->room_type,
              'description'=>$request->description,
              'max_adults'=>$request->max_adults,
              'max_children'=>$request->max_children,
              'price'=>$request->price,
              'status'=> $request->status,
          ];
        $room_type = RoomType::create($data_room);
```

The status should return value 0 in a false case and 1 in true case but it only returns 1 in the true case and null in a false case. it supposed to return 0 but it returns null

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getValue() {
  if (document.getElementById('togBtn').checked) {
    console.log("Checked");
    document.getElementById('togBtn').setAttribute("value", "0");

  } else {
    console.log("Not Checked");
    document.getElementById('togBtn').setAttribute("value", "1");
  }
  console.log(document.getElementById('togBtn').getAttribute("value"));

}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-size="large" id="togBtn" name="status" value="1" onclick="getValue()">
```

You can do something like this to set a particular value. You can check Checked not checked then you can pass the data according to checked unchecked value

Comment: its works fine in the console but when I try to save It into database ..only the true value gets stored but false value return null

Comment: Brother, please add code snippet So I can help you in a better way.

Comment: bro i have updated the code , please help me with that

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to get this input's value to submit?

Try this:

```
var a = $('#togBtn').prop("checked") ? 1 : 0 ;
// to submit ...
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

check this one :

```
let value = 0
if($("#togBtn").is(":checked")){
    value = 1;
}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.